# React JS Mapping Array and Unpacking Specific Values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary

I am trying to map over specific values in an array of objects.
I have collected data from my Backend API and this is the response:

```
// An array of objects
console.log(response.data) = 
[
    {name:"Bryan",age:"25",sport:"basketball"},
    {name:"Justin",age:"30",sport:"soccer"},
    {name:"Mark",age:"28",sport:"basketball"},
    {name:"Cowell",age:"27",sport:"soccer"},
]
```

I put this data into a state ("data") using "useState()" from React and used a useEffect to unpack the data upon rendering.

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])

// some function to store response.data in state
setData(response.data)
```

I want to map these values onto my Browser in the following way such that Soccer players are displayed in the first div and Basketball players in the second div:
(tried several ways but they resulted in parsing errors)

```
function App() {
    const [data, showData] = useState([])

    return (
      <div>
         {data.map(info => {
              <div>
                 <h1> Sport: soccer </h1> 
                 <h5> {info.name} </h5>
              </div>

              <div>
                 <h1> Sport: basketball</h1> 
                 <h5> {info.name} </h5>
              </div>
           }
         )}
      </div>
    )
}
```

I am trying to group the names within the same div block (same sport) and not 2 different div blocks for each sport.

Comment: You're not returning anything from the map

Comment: It does return but it returns all their names instead of the specific category "Soccer" and "Basketball".

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the elements from the map function and also remove the part where you hardcode basketball.

```
{data.map((info, idx) => (
  <div key={idx}>
    <h1> Sport: {info.sport} </h1>
    <h5> {info.name} </h5>
  </div>
))}
```

```js
const groupBy = (array, getGroupByKey) => {
  return (
    (array &&
      array.reduce((grouped, obj) => {
        const groupByKey = getGroupByKey(obj);

        if (!grouped[groupByKey]) {
          grouped[groupByKey] = [];
        }

        grouped[groupByKey].push(obj);

        return grouped;
      }, {})) ||
    {}
  );
};

const App = (props) => {
  var [data, setData] = React.useState([
    { name: 'Bryan', age: '25', sport: 'basketball' },
    { name: 'Justin', age: '30', sport: 'soccer' },
    { name: 'Mark', age: '28', sport: 'basketball' },
    { name: 'Cowell', age: '27', sport: 'soccer' },
  ]);

  const players = groupBy(data, (player) => player.sport);
  const sportKeys = Object.keys(players);



  return (
    <div>
      {sportKeys.map((info, idx) => (
        <div key={idx}>
          <h1> Sport: {info} </h1>
          {players[info].map((player, i) => (
            <h5 key={i}>{player.name}</h5>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: This works! However, I am trying to group the names within the same div block (same sport). This creates 2 div blocks for each sport.

Comment: You need to group the data first then display it. I've updated my answer.